# JOOQ DSL way of working around ORA-01489 in LISTAGG()

Tags: oracle11g, jooq

In Oracle SQL there is this workaround using XMLAGG instead of LISTAGG when the resulting text would be too large for VARCHAR2 (error message: `ORA-01489 Result of string concat is too large`).

SQL example:

```sql
LISTAGG(MY_TEXT_SNIPPET) WITHIN GROUP (order by SNIPPET_NO)
```

workaround

```sql
RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, MY_TEXT_SNIPPET,'').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY SNIPPET_NO).GetClobVal(),',')
```

How would you do the latter with JOOQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the XML functions are supported starting from jOOQ 3.14, including:

- [`XMLAGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/xml-agg-function/)
- [`XMLELEMENT`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/xml-functions/xml-element-function/)

But neither `EXTRACT()` nor `GetClobVal()` are supported yet in this form. You try using [`XMLQUERY()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/xml-functions/xml-query-function/) and casting to `CLOB` instead.

Alternatively, as always when a vendor-specific feature isn't supported, you can resort to using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/):

**Mixing jOOQ API with templates**

```java
public static Field<String> listAggWorkaround(Field<?> field, Field<?> orderBy) {
  return rtrim(
    field("{0}.GetClobVal()", SQLDataType.CLOB, 
      xmlagg(field("{0}.extract('//text()')", SQLDataType.XML, 
        xmlelement("e", field, inline(""))
      )).orderBy(orderBy)
    ),
    inline(",")
  );
}
```

**Using only templates**

```java
public static Field<String> listAggWorkaround(Field<?> field, Field<?> orderBy) {
  return field(
    "rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,{0},'').extract('//text()') order by {1}).GetClobVal(),',')", 
    SQLDataType.CLOB,
    field, orderBy
  );
}
```